# AS-Path Modification on BGP Neighbors

Tags: routes, router, default, bgp, wan

In my network, I have four routers (R1, R2, R3, and R4), and I am utilizing BGP for routing.
The objective is to ensure that all traffic from R4 to the destination 8.8.8.8 follows the path through R3 as the primary route, with R2 acting as the backup route.
I am attempting to achieve this goal by modifying the AS-Path attribute.

Current scenario:

```
R4#traceroute 8.8.8.8 source 4.4.4.4
Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to 8.8.8.8
VRF info: (vrf in name/id, vrf out name/id)
  1 24.24.24.2 0 msec 2 msec 1 msec
  2 12.12.12.1 0 msec 1 msec *
```

How to modify the AS-Path attribute on R4 to accomplish this goal? Additionally, are there alternative methods to achieve the same objective, such as configuring static routes?

[image]

[image]